# Visual 2017 Code Analysis Project Property Page throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, projects-and-solutions

On any project that I attempt to enable Code Analysis, Visual Studio (2017) throws an error "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" error message box. If I then try to close the project document tab, the same error message is shown.

This happens on new or existing solutions/projects.

Nothing is showing up in the event log.

Is there a possible workaround or known issue for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a Visual Studio "Repair" with the VS 2017 Installer seems to have resolved the issue.